# Have a message box show on top of installer or after application closes?

Tags: c#, .net, installation, messagebox

So in my installer I have a command line argument sent to my program to register a server, then a messagebox is created, indicating successful registration, then the program closes.

Now an issue here is that the installer stops and waits for the program to close before continuing. Another issue is that this message is shown behind the installer window so there's a chance the user may miss this and just think the installer is faulty.

Is there anyway to have the messagebox appear in front of the installer? Note that I've tried using `MessageBox.Show(this, "myMessage");` However this actually makes the messagebox not appear at all.

And then is there a way to either close application while leaving the message box open? Or instead make the installer continue even though the app is still open?

Here's the installer project I'm using:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I got the message box to show on top of all other applications by calling it like so:

```
                    MessageBox.Show(
                        "Server registered successfully!", 
                        "Gyptech Micrometer OPC Server",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Information,
                        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
                        MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
```

The vital part being that last parameter, `MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly`. Now the box shows over top of the installer : )

Comment: This is a hack that should not be necessary unless your installer is actually running on a different desktop. What you want to do is specify the *owner window* for the dialog box, which is the first parameter in certain overloads of `Show`. You tried passing `this`, but you didn't say what `this` was. It needs to be your installer window, the window that is currently in the foreground. That way, if it displays an owned window, the owned window will always be in front, because an owned window is always in front of its parent in the Z order.

Comment: @CodyGray This makes a lot of sense...Just not sure how to do this. Uhm, speaking from a synstax perspective, how do I write something like `"thisInstallerWindow"` instead of just `this`?

Comment: @CodyGray if you know how to code the answer you've suggested would you mind contributing it as an answer with example code? That would probably help me best. : )

Comment: Well, I have no idea what your installer code looks like, or I would have suggested it in the first comment. :-) There isn't enough information in the question to tell. Generally, `this` is sufficient if `this` is a form/window on top of which you want the dialog displayed. The coding part is trivial, once you figure out what the owner window is supposed to be. That's the part I don't know without seeing more of the code.

Comment: @CodyGray Oh yeah so here's the thing. I haven't really made an installer class. I'm not sure how this works but I'm using "Setup Project", a template I got from an extension called installer for visual studio 2015. Do you know the one I'm talking about? I guess I'm struggling to figure out what the name of that installer window is and how I can access it.

Comment: I know vaguely what you mean, but they've changed the built-in setup project generator and how it works (or if it's even included at all) repeatedly with the last several versions of Visual Studio, and I just can't keep up anymore. I don't use it; I use Inno Setup. I don't have a machine running VS in front of me, so I can't fire it up and check. Maybe I'll check back tomorrow when I get a chance.

Comment: @CodyGray I've added a picture into OP as an edit to show you the project I'm working with. Does that clear things up?

Comment: Actually, this option makes the message appear on top of _any_ window until it is closed, which is not always desirable. Could not find anything better, though.

Answer (score -1):

```
MessageBox.Show("MyMessage");
```

You don't need to send `this` as your first argument.  It's generally implied.  That being said, it also doesn't adversely effect what you're trying to do.  There's  a bunch of different arguments it can take.  Check them out here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx

You can edit the `Caption`, `Icon`'s, and `Button`'s within the `MessageBox`.

If we can see the rest of the code involved, it would help solve your problem.

Comment: It is not at all clear to me how this answers the question. You just give a mostly-correct run-down of how the MessageBox.Show function works. If your goal was to say that we need to see the rest of the code to help, you should have posted that as a comment, instead of an answer.

Comment: Well thanks for that gem of insight Cody.  Looks like my referring him to MSDN actually helped him solve his problem, but what do I know?

Comment: That would be another compelling argument for it being posted as a comment, since it was a push in the right direction, rather than a self-contained answer. To be clear, I didn't intend for you to take offense at my comment. I just don't understand how this answers the actual question being asked, which is a rather specific question about showing a message box on top of another application/window, and while the information you've provided is certainly useful, I think it would be more appropriate as a comment. We have pretty strict standards around here about what constitutes an answer.

Comment: Again, after my answer was posted, it would appear that Mr. Doe found what he was looking for.  If you thought my answer was inconsequential or insufficient, then you can post your own answer that clarifies things more.  I understand that your trying to be the hero of Stack Overflow content and all that, but your comments and edits serve far less value than my answer.  I'm not offended - just don't criticize if you don't have anything to contribute.